# How to read from file and output to html table with AWK

Tags: awk

I'm newby in AWK and I know its not a specific question. I just need some advice how should i do this.

Given the following names in a file, **author.list:**

```
KOVACS PETER
Kiss Roland
Nagy jolan
Lisztes Tibor
Feher aNDRas
Korma Maria
Akarki Jack
```

write an AWK program that can read the names from the file and print them to an html table with a three-column format in an output file, **output.html.** The table should render like this:

```
    Kovacs Peter     Lisztes Tibor    Akarki Jack
    Kiss Roland      Feher Andras
    Nagy Jolan       Korma Maria
```

*An example execution:*

```
awk -f convert.awk author.list > output.html
```

Ensure that **output.html** is a valid html file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And who thought this was a good exercise for learning AWK?

Comment: @Cerberus, edit you **question**. And do it according to the feedback you receive here in the comments.

Comment: You say `The table should render like this` but we don't care about that, we care about helping you generate the HTML that would cause the table to render like this. So, [edit] your question to show the HTML you want the awk script to output as THAT is what you're (hopefully!)  really asking us for help with.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the HTML you want to generate it's a guess but this might be what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    print "<html>"
    print "  <table>"
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        $i = toupper(substr($i,1,1)) tolower(substr($i,2))
    }
    if ( (NR%3) == 1 ) {
        if (NR>1) print "      </tr>"
        print "      <tr>"
    }
    printf "        <td>%s</td>\n", $0
}
END {
    for (i=NR+1; (i%3) != 1; i++) {
        printf "        <td>%s</td>\n", ""
    }
    print "      </tr>"

    print "  </table>"
    print "</html>"
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk author.list
<html>
  <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Kovacs Peter</td>
        <td>Kiss Roland</td>
        <td>Nagy Jolan</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lisztes Tibor</td>
        <td>Feher Andras</td>
        <td>Korma Maria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Akarki Jack</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

The name upper/lower case conversion will fail on names like `McDonald` or `O'Hara` or `Billy-Bob` that don't only have 1 capital letter at the start of the name. If you have to handle that then you need to provide an algorithm.