# Create XML with awk command with text file

Tags: xml, awk, salesforce

I have a text file with following data, need to convert it into xml with awk command in shell script.

```
Package1,class1
Package1,class2
Package2,Page1
Package2,Page2
```

This text file need to be converted into xml as shown in below format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>class1</members>
        <members>class2</members>
        <name>Package1</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Page1</members>
        <members>Page2</members>
        <name>Package2</name>
    </types>
<version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

i am new to shell script. please help me out....

Comment: There';s a lot of examples of doing that on this forum, search the archives.

Comment: Thanks Ed. Can you please help me with one relavent example. I referred this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48866831/awk-script-create-xml-file. I am not sure how to get in mentioned format.

Comment: Just post a question with a [mcve] that includes concise, testable sample input plus expected output plus the code you've tried to use. If that's code from some existing answer that you've tried to modify to your purposes but can't that's fine.

Comment: You might want to use something simpler and seemingly more relevant like https://stackoverflow.com/a/61011897/1745001 as your starting point though.

Answer (score 0):

this should get you started

```
$  awk -F, 'function wrap(t,v) {return "<"t">"v"</"t">"}
            function rec()     {return wrap("types", members ORS wrap("name",$1) ORS)}                
            p && p!=$1 {print rec(); members=""}     
                       {p=$1; members=members ORS wrap("member",$2)} 
            END        {print rec()}' file

<types>
<member>class1</member>
<member>class2</member>
<name>Package2</name>
</types>
<types>
<member>Page1</member>
<member>Page2</member>
<name>Package2</name>
</types>
```

build up the record until the name changes and print.

Comment: This helps for building xml but I got output as following.

<types>
</member>
 <name></name>
 </types>
 <types>
 <member></member>
 </member>
 <name></name>
 </types>
 <types>
 <member></member>
 </member>
 <name></name>
 </types>
 <types>
 <member></member>
 </member>
 <name></name>
 </types>
 <types>
 <member></member>
 <name></name>
 </types>

Comment: Either your input file is not as shown or you didn't copy the script correctly. Also the output you posted is not possible, missing the initial `<member>`